# Document webAPI in webpage of API

Tags: documentation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a webAPI in which I have many functions.  I would like to create a page that will describe the api when a user goes to the api link.

Example:

I have the link: https://coreapi.pexcard.com/v2/Admin/ping

My route looks like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{action}/operation/{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = "ping" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultPageView",
            url: "{action}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action="Index", page = "Admin"}
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new {   }
        );
```

When the user goes to https://coreapi.pexcard.com/v2/Admin/  I want to forward them to a page in my repository that has the definition of the API(including all functions).  I got this done by making the HomeController as follows:

```
    public ActionResult Admin(string page)
    {
        return View("Admin/" + page );
    }
```

then when I go to the website I can get to a webpage that I will put my content on and when I click the ping link on that webpage(the webpage is live) it will get me to the ping description.

I feel that there should be a better way to do this.  Does anyone know of any built in functionality to ASP.NET to make this cleaner or better?

Comment: Checkout nuget package "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" to see if it fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

As Kiran states. Sounds like Web Api help pages should do the job. You might need to make sure you VS is up to date first.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages

Comment: I've used this package a few times now and it's pretty easy to set up. It automatically scans your project and generates documentation, complete with example input/output.